# Parsing Facebook API calls - NSDictionary NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

Seem to be having issues accessing the data from a Facebook API call. The returned data comes in the following order:

```
{
comments =     {
    data =         (
                    {
        }
    )
}
}
```

Been trying for ages, but how would I access the data / comments in this scenario? My code is something along the lines of:

```
NSLog(@"%@",allData);

for (NSDictionary *item in allData) {
    NSDictionary *comments = [item objectForKey:@"comments"];
    //ALSO TRIED
    NSArray *comments = [item objectForKey:@"comments"];
}
```

Both of the above methods seem to throw up an error

Answer (score 0):

Argh, what a plum!

Basically didn't need the for loop, so it would just be:

```
[allData objectForKey:@"comments"]
```

Thanks guys, will leave this up for others :D